# PHP $_SESSION array - only showing current index

Tags: php, session

I am trying to make a $_SESSION array that takes multiple array items from a $_SESSION button when clicked. I am able to output the total array length, as well as the current number of clicks.

However, I cannot seem to be able to display the clicks in order. For example, here is my output:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 ) 3
```

3 is the number of clicks, with 3 outside of () being the counter. How can I make it so my array looks like this?

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 3
```

Here is my code:

```
session_start();
    
    // Keeps track of the amount of clicks
    $_SESSION['Counter_Value'];
    // The array itself
    $_SESSION['Counter'] = array($_SESSION['Counter_Value']);

    // keeps the array from being empty
    if(empty($_SESSION['Counter_Value'])) {
                $_SESSION['Counter_Value'] = 0;
            }
// This is the code for the button
if(isset($_POST['Btn1'])) {
        // Adds to the value of the counter
        $_SESSION['Counter_Value']++;
        // Every time a button is clicked, its value goes to the $_SESSION array'
        array_push($_SESSION['Counter'], $_SESSION['Counter_Value']);
}


// On Main Page
        session_start();
        
        // This outputs $_SESSION['Counter'] and displays first 3 results
        $_SESSION['Counter'] = array_fill(0,3,$_SESSION['Counter_Value']);
        // prints out array
        print_r($_SESSION['Counter']);
        // prints out amount of clicks
        echo $_SESSION['Counter_Value'];
```

Comment: Remove   `$_SESSION['Counter'] = array_fill(0,3,$_SESSION['Counter_Value']);`

Comment: When I try that the array is blank

Comment: That line of code fills the first 3 elements of `$_SESSION['Counter']` with the same value and that is the number contained in `$_SESSION['Counter_Value']`. If now it's empty, it means that has not been filled by the other piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

With `$_SESSION['Counter'] = array($_SESSION['Counter_Value']);` you reset $_SESSION['Counter'] on each call.

Simplify a bit and retry:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['Counter_Value'])) {
    $_SESSION['Counter_Value'] = 0;
}

if(isset($_POST['Btn1'])) {
   $_SESSION['Counter_Value']++;
   $_SESSION['Counter'][] = $_SESSION['Counter_Value'];
}
```